# Azure SFTP file transfer to Blob storage

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage

I'm trying to add functionality to transfer files to Blob Storage through SFTP.
I'm using [sftp-creation-template](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/sftp-creation-template). However, this solution only works with File Share.
I wonder if there is a possibility to make it work with Blob? If not, what should I do, to sync content between Blob and File Share?

Comment: Please see this: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/resources/templates/101-logic-app-ftp-to-blob/. It uses a Logic App to transfer files from FTP to Blob Storage.

Comment: What do you mean to sync content between Blob and File Share, unidirection from one to another, or bidirection between them?

Comment: @PeterPan Bi-direction between them

Comment: We use Azure Data Factory with SFTP Linked Service, and binary DataSets to transfer from SFTP to Blob Storage.